# connection object from hikaricp connection pool

Tags: java, connection-pooling, hikaricp

I am using hikaricp (this would probably apply to any other Database connection pool as well).  I have a DBPool class in which I instantiate a HikariDataSource (using the HikariConfig object).  I am using the lazy holder idiom for this DBPool to limit one pool instance per VM.  However, once you get a reference to the pool, you can retrieve the Connection object (without any further locks/synchronization/semaphore checks) since I thought the connection pool would take care of my connection object limits.  Evertime I get the connection reference via the DBPool, I call close on the connection/preparedstatement/resultset.  I could try a try with resources if that's causing an issue. 
I am observing the following in the logs:

```
2014-09-14 18:53:25,302 WARN c.z.h.p.LeakTask [Hikari Housekeeping Timer (pool testHikariCp)] Connection leak detection triggered, stack trace follows java.lang.Exception
        at com.akkadian.db.DBConnPool.getConnection(DBConnPool.java:67)
        at models.tester.storeload.testAlertLogStoreLoad.loadAll(testAlertChk.java:101)
        at com.testLib.map.MapStoreWrapper.loadAll(MapStoreWrapper.java:131)
        at com.testLib.map.mapstore.AbstractMapDataStore.loadAll(AbstractMapDataStore.java:40)
        at com.testLib.map.BasicRecordStoreLoader$MapLoadAllTask.run(BasicRecordStoreLoader.java:340)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at com.testLib.util.executor.CompletableFutureTask.run(CompletableFutureTask.java:57)
        at com.testLib.util.executor.CachedExecutorServiceDelegate$Worker.run(CachedExecutorServiceDelegate.java:209)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        at com.testLib.util.executor.testLibManagedThread.executeRun(testLibManagedThread.java:76)
        at com.testLib.util.executor.testLibManagedThread.run(testLibManagedThread.java:92)
```

I increased the connection timeout and set the leakDetectionthreshold as follows:

```
     hikariConfig.setConnectionTimeout(90000); 
     hikariConfig.setLeakDetectionThreshold(10000);
```

I also increased the size of the pool even though it was recommended not to - I had to test various options since I was receiving connection timeouts from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you are indeed releasing the connection back to the pool? Can you use try with resources (in addition to increasing threshold as Brett mentioned):

```
try (Connection conn = DBConnectionPool.getConnection(); 
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(preparedQuery);) {
```

and the resultset (because some drivers/databases may not clean out resultset when connection is cleaned though not sure if this is still valid for new drivers/databases but I'm not sure what you are using):

try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();) {

Increase the leak detection threshold if needed though I think if you have to make it too large, you have an issue which needs to be fixed.